# How to stop a foreground service from the notification in android?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am using a foreground service in my application I need to stop this service from a button that is present on the notification itself without opening the activity.
My current code

This is my activity from where I am starting the service.

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BackgroundService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ip",ipAdd);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("token",token);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("port",portNo);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("resource",resourceId);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("userName",username);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        ClosingBackGroundService.getMainActivityContext(MainActivity.this);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopService(serviceIntent);
            }
        });
```

I am using a class to show the button on the notification and trying to close the activity

```
public class ClosingBackGroundService extends BroadcastReceiver {

   static Context mainActContext;
    public static void getMainActivityContext(Context context){
        mainActContext = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       mainActContext.stopService(MainActivity.serviceIntent);
        Log.i("Service","closed");
    }
}
```

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
       registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);
        Intent closingIntent = new Intent(this,ClosingBackGroundService.class);
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,closingIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setOngoing(true)
             .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Close Services",actionIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText("Processes Running In BackGround").build();
    ipAdd = intent.getStringExtra("ip");
    port = intent.getStringExtra("port");
    token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
    resourceId = intent.getIntExtra("resource",0);
    username = intent.getStringExtra("userName");
    runnableForGps.run();
    runnableForSendingGpsData.run();
    runnableForBluetooth.run();
    runnableForsendingBTData.run();
    startForeground(1,notification);

    return START_STICKY;
    }
```

When I press the button the notification disappears but the process keeps on working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create `BroadCast` to stop `Service`. Try this

```
private static final String ACTION_STOP_LISTEN = "action_stop_listen";
```

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClosingBackGroundService.class);
intent.setAction(ACTION_STOP_LISTEN);
PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,"Close Services",actionIntent)
```

In `onStartCommand` check your `Intent` action

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null && ACTION_STOP_LISTEN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        // your code
}
```